# Проблема с чтениям файла с помощью BinaryReader

Tags: c#, .net

Работаю над проектом и при чтении файла возникает ошибка.
Метод в котором ошибка.

```
System.FormatException: 'Слишком много байтов в элементе, который должен быть 7-битным элементом Int32 с кодировкой'.
```

Я понимаю как возникает ошибка и почему она возникает, но я не могу понять как ее исправить. Помогите пожалуйста

```cs
public void ReadFile()
{
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open($@"C:\Users\User\source\repos\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\bin\Debug\Teachers.dat", FileMode.Open)))
    {          
        while (reader.PeekChar() > -1)
        {
            CurrentId = reader.ReadInt32();
            Surname = reader.ReadString();
            Name = reader.ReadString();
            Middlename = reader.ReadString();
            Year_of_Birth = reader.ReadInt32();                    
        }
    }
}
```

Запись в файл

```cs
public void WriteFile()
{
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open($@"C:\Users\User\source\repos\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\bin\Debug\Teachers.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
    {
        writer.Write(CurrentId);
        writer.Write(Surname); 
        writer.Write(Name);
        writer.Write(Middlename);
        writer.Write(Year_of_Birth);
  
        for(int i = 0; i < Discipline.Length; i++)
        {
            writer.Write(Discipline[i]);
        }
   
        for(int i = 0; i < Groups.Length; i++)
        {
            writer.Write(Groups[i]);
        }
        writer.Write(Login);
        writer.Write(Password);    
    }
}
```

Данные класса

```
public static string Surname;//Фамилия
public static string Name;//Имя
public static string Middlename;//Очество       
public static int Year_of_Birth;//Год рождения
public static string[] Discipline;
public static string[] Groups;//Группа (можно с буквами)
public static string Login;//Логин
public static string Password;//Пароль
public static int CurrentId = -1;
```

Comment: А файл то у вас бинарный или текстовый? А то похоже, что вы текстовый файл пытаетесь читать как бинарный. Зачем?

Comment: Текстовый файл, но бинарные данные

Comment: Покажите файл ))

Comment: могу кинуть код записи в файл

Comment: А какую задачу вы решаете. Это кстасти у вас .NET Framework или .NET 5? Покажите код класса с данными.

Comment: Расширение файла уже поменяла на .dat и у меня .NET Framework

Comment: Задача какая у вас, сохранить данные, или именно с использованием `BinaryWriter`?

Comment: Задача "Все данные хранить в бинарных файлах" расширение уже сменила на .bin

Comment: Ну, у вас же чтение и запись несимметричны? Вы записываете `Discipline`, `Groups`, `Login`, `Password`, но не читаете их.

Comment: @CrazyElf оч смешно :) вам X2 или Base64? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обо всех ошибках по порядку.

- Предположим, что учителей у вас больше одного, поэтому использование `static` полей недопустимо.
- Чтобы их всех хранить, нужна коллекция или массив. Самый простой вариант с возможностью удаления и добавления элементов - список `List`.
- Ошибку, которую вы указали в вопросе, я не смог воспроизвести. Но думаю, что она заключалась в том, что вы использовали [FileMode.OpenOrCreate](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=netframework-4.8). В этом режиме, если файл существует, он будет дозаписан в конец, а не перезаписан полностью. Вам нужно было использовать режим `FileMode.Create` для полной перезаписи файла. А так, вы просто открывали на чтение и читали белиберду, которая была вами туда записана при первом создании файла, после которого код чтения и записи наверное менялся несколько раз.
- Методы чтения и записи (как указал в комментариях @VladD) должны быть симметричны. То есть формат записываемых данных должен на 100% совпадать с форматом читаемых.
- Чтобы прочитать массив с помощью `BinaryReader`, вам потребуется длина массива, иначе вы не сможете узнать, сколько там элементов массива лежит в файле.
- Пароль в открытом виде хранить нелья, шифровать с ключом безопасности и хранить ключ тоже нельзя, а то будет похоже на запертую дверь с ключом, висящим рядом на крючке. Для решения этой проблемы есть алгоритмы хеширования. Хэш, это когда мы можем данные преобразовать в некий их отпечаток, а обратное преобразование вообще невозможно, только методом полного перебора всех хэшей. А это очень тяжелая для компьютера задача. Самый простой, но не самый надежный алгоритм хэширования - MD5, его я и буду использовать. Как же сравнить пароль с хэшом сохраненного пароля? Все просто, получить хэш введенного пароля и сравнить хэши. Таким образом работает любой сайт или приложение, куда вы вводите свой пароль.

**Теперь к делу**

Класс, хранящий данные

```cs
public class Teacher
{
    private string passwordHash;
    public int Id { get; set; } = -1;
    public string Surname { get; set; }//Фамилия
    public string Name { get; set; } //Имя
    public string Middlename { get; set; } //Очество       
    public int YearOfTheBirth { get; set; } //Год рождения
    public string[] Disciplines { get; set; }
    public string[] Groups { get; set; }//Группа (можно с буквами)
    public string Login { get; set; } //Логин
    public string Password//Пароль
    {
        get => passwordHash;
        set
        {
            MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
            byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
            passwordHash = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        }
    }

    public bool CheckPassword(string password)
    {
        MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
        byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
        return passwordHash == Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }

    public void SetPasswordHash(string hash)
    {
        passwordHash = hash;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Id}: {Surname} {Name} {Middlename}, {YearOfTheBirth}, Дисциплины: {string.Join(" ", Disciplines)}, Группы: {string.Join(" ", Groups)}, {Login}:{Password}";
    }
}
```

Как видно, обеспечение безопасности при хранении пароля происходит прямо здесь. То есть открытый пароль условно даже в оперативной памяти у вас не хранится. Обратите внимание на ассиметричность свойства `Password`, присваивать ему надо открытый пароль, а отдавать оно вам будет уже хэш. Вы можете переделать как вам понятнее, но я решил сделать вот так.

Список учителей объявляется так. Давайте сразу наполню его тестовыми данными.

```
List<Teacher> teachers = new List<Teacher>();
teachers.Add(new Teacher
{
    Id = 1,
    Surname = "Базука",
    Name = "Ангелина",
    Middlename = "Петровна",
    YearOfTheBirth = 1960,
    Disciplines = new string[]
    {
        "Геометрия",
        "Алгебра"
    },
    Groups = new string[]
    {
        "Ы18",
        "Э24"
    },
    Login = "a_bazooka",
    Password = "puga4eva"
});
teachers.Add(new Teacher
{
    Id = 2,
    Surname = "Иванова",
    Name = "Наталья",
    Middlename = "Сидоровна",
    YearOfTheBirth = 1981,
    Disciplines = new string[]
    {
        "Физика",
        "Астрономия"
    },
    Groups = new string[]
    {
        "Ы18",
        "У13"
    },
    Login = "n_sidorova",
    Password = "bazookadura"
});
```

При этом если вы захотите посмотреть сохраненный пароль

```cs
Console.WriteLine(teachers[0].Password);
```

Вы получите такой вывод

```
0NMTx9+TQ0z4UPpsgS2vkA==
```

А если програмно захотите сверить введенный пароль пользователя

```cs
Console.WriteLine(teachers[0].CheckPassword("puga4eva"));
```

То вывод будет такой

```
True
```

Собственно, цель формирования модели данных достигнута, с данными работать получается. Безопасность хранения паролей не нарушена.

Загрузка и запись.

```cs
private static void SaveTeachers(List<Teacher> teachers)
{
    using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Create("teachers.bin")))
    {
        foreach (Teacher teacher in teachers)
        {
            bw.Write(teacher.Id);
            bw.Write(teacher.Surname);
            bw.Write(teacher.Name);
            bw.Write(teacher.Middlename);
            bw.Write(teacher.YearOfTheBirth);
            bw.Write(teacher.Disciplines.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < teacher.Disciplines.Length; i++)
                bw.Write(teacher.Disciplines[i]);
            bw.Write(teacher.Groups.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < teacher.Groups.Length; i++)
                bw.Write(teacher.Groups[i]);
            bw.Write(teacher.Login);
            bw.Write(teacher.Password);
        }
    }
}

private static List<Teacher> LoadTeachers()
{
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("teachers.bin")))
    {
        List<Teacher> teachers = new List<Teacher>();
        while (br.PeekChar() > -1)
        {
            Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
            teacher.Id = br.ReadInt32();
            teacher.Surname = br.ReadString();
            teacher.Name = br.ReadString();
            teacher.Middlename = br.ReadString();
            teacher.YearOfTheBirth = br.ReadInt32();
            teacher.Disciplines = new string[br.ReadInt32()];
            for (int i = 0; i < teacher.Disciplines.Length; i++)
                teacher.Disciplines[i] = br.ReadString();
            teacher.Groups = new string[br.ReadInt32()];
            for (int i = 0; i < teacher.Groups.Length; i++)
                teacher.Groups[i] = br.ReadString();
            teacher.Login = br.ReadString();
            teacher.SetPasswordHash(br.ReadString());
            teachers.Add(teacher);
        }
        return teachers;
    }
}
```

Здесь должно быть для вас все просто.

Ну и потестируем.

Сохраним данные.

```cs
SaveTeachers(teachers);
```

Загрузим в другой список и выведем в консоль

```cs
List<Teacher> loadedTeachers = LoadTeachers();
foreach (Teacher teacher in loadedTeachers)
    Console.WriteLine(teacher);
```

И получим вот такой вывод в консоль

```
1: Базука Ангелина Петровна, 1960, Дисциплины: Геометрия Алгебра, Группы: Ы18 Э24, a_bazooka:0NMTx9+TQ0z4UPpsgS2vkA==
2: Иванова Наталья Сидоровна, 1981, Дисциплины: Физика Астрономия, Группы: Ы18 У13, n_sidorova:VGTnUrczl1WDcXENQZo45w==
```

Как видно, данные успешно загружены.

Кстати, за формат вывода данных в консоль отвечает переопределенный метод `ToString()` в классе `Teacher`. Берите на вооружение.

Comment: Спасибо очень помогли

Comment: @Yanok я дописал про то, в чем именно была у вас ошибка.

Comment: и этим очень сильно помогли я с этим уже 2 дня страдаю

Comment: @Yanok кстати, если вам не нужно строковое представление пароля, то вы можете `passwordHash` заменить на `byte[]` и убрать преобразование из/в `Base64`. Я использовал `Base64` только для того чтобы можно было текстовм образом показать пример хешированного пароля. Но тогда при записи массива байт вам придется так же сохранить его длину. Еще так как тип `passwordHash` не будет совпадать с типом свойства `Password`, то придется логику взаимодействия с ними разделить. В общем, смотрите сами, `Base64` здесь опционален и от него можно избавиться.