# Реализация через cериализацию. Файл с расписанием

Tags: c#, сериализация

Не знаю, как правильно задать объекты и какой длины. Не понимаю должны ли иметь массивы групп отсылку на следующие массивы подгрупп (то есть должны ли они быть как-то связанны между собой)

Задача:

> а) Для конкретного дня недели, номера группы и подгруппы и ленты выдать какой предмет должен быть по расписанию (если занятия нет, то выдать сообщение об этом)
>
> б) Для заданной группы составить расписание на неделю (должна делать программа вручную либо рандомайзером)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace weekSchedule
{ 
        [Serializable()]
        public struct Schedule
        {
            public int group;
            public char SubGroup;
            public string predmet;
            public char day;
            public char lenta;

            public void DisplayInfo()
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine($"Группа: {group}  " + "\n" +
                                  $"Подгруппа: {SubGroup}" + "\n" +
                                  $"День: {day}" + "\n" +
                                  $"Номер ленты: {lenta}" + "\n" +
                                  $"Предмет: {predmet}");
            }
        }

        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string filename = "test.dat";
                Schedule[] ScheduleToSave = new Schedule[5];

                /*заполняем данными
                 ....
                
                 */
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                FileStream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(filename);
                formatter.Serialize(outputStream, ScheduleToSave);
                outputStream.Close();

                FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(filename);
                Schedule[] loadedAddresses = (Schedule[])formatter.Deserialize(inputStream);
                inputStream.Close();
            }
        }
    
}
```

Comment: то есть о своей задаче вы не пишете, но спрашиваете, верно ли вы её решаете?

Comment: извините , сейчас исправлю

Comment: @tym32167, написал

Comment: что такое "лента"?

Comment: И перед тем, как думать о сериализации, подумайте сначала какие классы вам понадобяистя с какими полями. У вас в задаче про сериализацию вообще ничего нет, то есть ваш вопрос с вашей задачей никак не связан.

Comment: А что за `подгруппы и ленты`? Что эти термины обозначают? Вам надо сначала создать классы всех необходимых сущностей, потом запрограммировать создание расписания, потом запрограммировать пункт `а)` из задания, а потом уже думать о сериализации.

Comment: @tym32167 Есть группа например 355 , подгруппа 2 , у них в день 2(Вторник), 4 Лентой , Предмет: Программирование

Comment: @aepot не совсем дубликат, тут нужен конкретный алгоритм через сериализацию

Comment: @Bulson что вы имеете ввиду под созданием классов всех необходимых сущностей?

Comment: Тогда в чем вопрос, вы не знаете, как работает сериализация? Если так, то напишите в вопросе конкретно, что именно не получается. Я пока вижу только использование устаревшего и опасного `BinaryFormatter`, который как я понял, вообще к вопросу отношения не имеет. В чём вопрос? Как записать класс на диск в бинарном формате? [Вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1216258/373567).

Comment: Если вопрос в том, как реализовать свою сериализацию, нужно унаследовать интерфейс `ISerializable` и реализовать его - [вот документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable?view=netframework-4.8)