# Как мне зашифровать пароль с помощью MD5 или другим методом в моей программе на C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

У меня есть десктопное приложение. В нём создана БД с данными пользователей. Как мне сделать так, чтобы логин и пароль хранились в виде хэша?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }
    Database data;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        data = new Database("base.db");
        data.InitializeDatabase();
        
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (data.ValidUser(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Добро пожаловать, {textBox1.Text}");
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            this.Hide();
            form2.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Неверный логин или пароль", "",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
           
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        data.registration(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
    }
}

 public class Database
{
    private string dbFileName;
    private SQLiteConnection dbConn;
    private SQLiteCommand m_sqlCmd;
    public Database(string name)
    {
        this.dbFileName = name;
    }
    public bool InitializeDatabase()
    {
        
        dbConn = new SQLiteConnection();
        m_sqlCmd = new SQLiteCommand();
        if (!File.Exists(dbFileName))
        {
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(dbFileName);

            dbConn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbFileName + ";Version=3;");
            dbConn.Open();
            m_sqlCmd.Connection = dbConn;
            m_sqlCmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
AUTOINCREMENT, login TEXT, password TEXT, role TEXT)";
            
            dbConn.Close();
        }
        return true;
        
    }
   
    public bool ValidUser(string username, string password)
    {
        SQLiteConnection dbConn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbFileName + 
";Version=3;");
        dbConn.Open();
        string Command = $"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE login = '{username}'";
        if ((Int64)new SQLiteCommand(Command, dbConn).ExecuteScalar() > 0)
        {
            Command = $"SELECT Password FROM users WHERE login = '{username}'";
            string PasswordHash = (string)new SQLiteCommand(Command, dbConn).ExecuteScalar();
            if (PasswordHash == password)
            {
                dbConn.Close();
                return true;
            }

        }
        dbConn.Close();
        return false;
    }
    public void registration(string username, string password)
    {
        SQLiteConnection dbConn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbFileName + 
";Version=3;");
        dbConn.Open();
        m_sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users ('login', 'password', 'role') values ('" + 
username + "' , '" + password + "', '" + "user" + "')";
        m_sqlCmd.Connection = dbConn;
        m_sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbConn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: MD5 - это метод хеширования, он не шифрует.

Comment: Здесь есть пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1216258/373567

Comment: А можно описать прям куда именно в коде это вставлять? Я просто плохо разбираюсь в C#, а работу на нём только писать можно

Comment: Ответ удален, так как не был принят.